# Cannot start GlassFish server via Terminal - No handler was ready to authenticate

Tags: glassfish, macos-sierra

I download the zip file of GlassFish 4.1.1, after extract it, I use Terminal to start the server using *asadmin start-domain* command. It give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/asadmin", line 260, in <module> autoscale = boto.connect_autoscale()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 208, in connect_autoscale**kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/autoscale/__init__.py", line 115, in __init__profile_name=profile_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1100, in __init__provider=provider)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 997, in get_auth_handler 'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names))) boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials
```

I'm using MacOS Sierra 10.12.2, anyone know how to fix that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you have the `boto` Python AWS command line utilities installed. One of those utilities is called `asadmin` and your shell thinks you mean to call the `asadmin` (AWS **a**uto**s**caling **admin**) command, rather than the GlassFish asadmin file.

After you extract GlassFish, you need to reference the `asadmin` file that comes with GlassFish, so start the domain as follows:

```
glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

Comment: how to reference asadmin to glassfish?

Comment: @StackUser I don't understand your question. It seems you are a Python user - if so, then GlassFish is not relevant for you and this answer won't help unfortunately.

Comment: If you want to find out what binary is providing any command in Linux, you can use the `which` command, e.g. `which asadmin` in this case will tell you what is being called when you type `asadmin` at the command line.

Comment: Sorry, I managed to do it with cmd cmd prompt. PowerShell was ignoring my path

Comment: Wow it was so obvious and I pulled my hair spending hours trying to figure this out, without realizing it was calling the wrong command! many thanks!